# Pandas Python: Delete row values by name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv list of keywords in this format:

```
75410,Sportart
75419,Ballsport
75428,Basketball
76207,Atomenergie
76212,Atomkraftwerk
76223,Wiederaufarbeitung
76225,Atomlager
67869,Werbewirtschaft
```

I read the values using pandas and create a table in this format:

```
DF:                            name
id
75410                 Sportart
75419                Ballsport
75428               Basketball
76207              Atomenergie
76212            Atomkraftwerk
...                        ...
251450           Tag und Nacht
241473      Kollektivverhalten
270930         Indigene Völker
261949  Wirtschaft und Politik
282512                  Impfen
```

Using the name, I want to delete the whole row, e.g. 'Sportart' deletes first row.
I want to check this with values from my wordList array, I store them as Strings in a list.

What did I miss? Using the code below I receive an '(value) not in axis' error.

```
 df = pd.read_csv("labels.csv", header=None, index_col=0)
    df.index.name = "id"
    df.columns = ["name"]
    print('DF: ',df)    
    df.drop(labels=wordList, axis=0,inplace=True)
    pd_frame = pd.DataFrame(df)

    cleaned_pd_frame = pd_frame.query('name != {}'.format(wordList))
```

I succeeded to hide them with query(), but I want to remove the entirely.
[image]

Comment: Note in the pandas [dataframe.drop() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the `labels` argument is "Index or column labels to drop. A tuple will be used as a single label and not treated as a list-like". The items you're trying to drop are not in the column or index labels. You can set the index to the `name` column, or use another method like a boolean mask with `~` and `.isin()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper function, `index_to_drop` below, to take in a name and filter its index out:

```
index_to_drop = lambda name: df.index[df['name']==name]
```

Then you can drop "Sportart" like:

```
df.drop(index_to_drop('Sportart'), inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       id                    name
1   75419               Ballsport
2   75428              Basketball
3   76207             Atomenergie
4   76212           Atomkraftwerk
5  251450           Tag und Nacht
6  241473      Kollektivverhalten
7  270930         Indigene Völker
8  261949  Wirtschaft und Politik
9  282512                  Impfen
```

That being said, this is just a convoluted way to drop a row. The same outcome can be obtained much simpler by using `isin`:

```
df = df[df['name']!='Sportart']
```